# Is it possible to create a generic EDMX model which work with both sql server and oracle?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

My application is developed by asp.net mvc and entity framework, considering that my EDMX model is generated from existing database within sql server 2012 and I would like to migrate my database schema to oracle, is it possible to use the same EDMX model which is generated from sql server 2012 schema to oracle database? Is it possible to create a generic EDMX model which work with both sql server and oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your EF model for multi provider from the following link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82017/Preparing-an-Entity-Framework-model-for-multi-prov.aspx

OR

other easy way, you can remove your model and connection string from your config and regenerate it again from oracle DB.

Comment: The application should work with sql server and oracle.

Comment: Any application can connect to multiple DB server without any problems but this case he has only one EF model and want to swap it between sql server and oracle DB

Comment: When I changed my connection string in order to connect with Oracle an error has been raised on save processing.

Comment: You can't only change your connection string you must also do  some bit work as mentioned in this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82017/Preparing-an-Entity-Framework-model-for-multi-prov.aspx or drop your model and recreate it again from oracle DB

Comment: I followed this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82017/Preparing-an-Entity-Framework-model-for-multi-prov.aspx but I got this error: the type varchar2 is not qualified with a namespace or alias